# Change style in p:inputText when required=true

Tags: java, css, primefaces

how to Change color in p:inputText when required = true, i dont want red color, this trouble is when the component is into p:dialog???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how java works, but with CSS you can do :

```
input[required] {
... your css
}
```

Comment: I try this but it doesnt work, when I use input[disabled] its works

Comment: try input[required="true"]

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this, and you can use base from parent.

```
P input[required] {
your css text color.
}
P input[disable] {
your css text color.
}
```

Comment: I m trying this: .foo[required] {
 background-color: #F3F781;
 border-color: #F3F781;
 
 
}